# robots.txt on apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, robots.txt, proxypass

I need some help with how to block the webcrawlers to go all the way to the webservers, but to stop the reverse proxy level and read the robots.txt file located at the root of the reverse proxy.

trying to accomplish my goal, I have configured the following:

`/etc/httpd/conf.d/servername.conf` as follows

```
<Location "/robots.txt">
  ProxyPass !
</Location>

<Location "/">
  ProxyPass balancer://servername/
</Location>
```

This does not help though...testing it, i can get all the way to the servername/robots.txt

Any ideas would be really appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Please indent the code in your question with 4 spaces. (Currently only `-----` is marked up as code.)

Answer (score 0):

got it...
the httpd service needed to restart

`service httpd graceful`

after restarting the service, i can see the robots.txt form reverse poxy kicking in :)